# Complex location in angular constructor is hard to test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am writing a test suite for a legacy app at work.
The app is written in Angular, with Karma and Jasmine for tests.

One of the components has this in the constructor:

```
if (this._location['_platformStrategy']['_platformLocation']['location']['pathname'].length > 2) {
      this.showBack = true;
    } else {
      this.showBack = false;
    }
```

It causes the base test to fail and the component to not be created.
The error I receive is:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_platformLocation' of null

How do I mock or stub the value in here?

What I mean by base test is:

```
it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I have tried multiple strategies to get around this and have not found a solution over the last few weeks. I have tried to mock the location in various places and to stub it.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i am assuming the this._location is the window location object. Either you can inject the mock window object and the set the value of the wjole object or you can add a comdition in the if block to add a null check for this._location. By this while executing the test it will always go to else block.